# SpringBatch(JdbcPagingItemReader) does not fetch all rows

Tags: sql-server-2012, spring-batch

I have a springbatch application and I am having trouble fetching all rows using JdbcPagingItemReader.

Total rows:

```sql
select count(*) from web_view;
```

Results in 12057 rows.

```
datasource.chunk.size=500
```

```java
@Bean
public PagingQueryProvider pagingQueryProvider() {
    SqlServerPagingQueryProvider sqlServerPagingQueryProvider = new SqlServerPagingQueryProvider();
    Map<String, Order> sortKey = new HashMap<>();
    sortKey.put("type", Order.ASCENDING);
    sqlServerPagingQueryProvider.setSelectClause("select *");
    sqlServerPagingQueryProvider.setFromClause("from web_view");
    sqlServerPagingQueryProvider.setSortKeys(sortKey);
    return sqlServerPagingQueryProvider;
}

@Bean
public JdbcPagingItemReader<Web> jdbcPagingItemReader() throws Exception {
    return new JdbcPagingItemReaderBuilder<Web>()
            .name("jdbcPagingItemReader")
            .dataSource(dataSource())
            .queryProvider(pagingQueryProvider())
            .rowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Web.class))
            .pageSize(chunkSize)
            .saveState(true)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Job importUserJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener jobCompletionNotificationListener, Step step1) {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("migrateWebJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .listener(jobCompletionNotificationListener)
            .flow(step1)
            .end()
            .build();
}
@Bean
public Step step1() throws Exception {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .<Web, WebStore>chunk(chunkSize)
            .reader(jdbcPagingItemReader())
            .processor(webStoreItemProcessor())
            .writer(eventHubItemWriter())
            .build();
}
```

It gracefully stops after 3rd paging processing only 1500 rows out of 12057.

Comment: I see nothing wrong in your config. The job should not stop after the third page. What is the exit status of the step/job? Can you enable debug and see if there is a (probably silently ignored) exception?

Comment: If you drop the sorting keys does it still stop?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine. I enabled debug and I do not see any exception. The job after 3rd paging says "20:01:11.872 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate - Repeat is complete according to policy and result value.
20:01:11.872 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.c.s.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet - Inputs not busy, ended: true" .

Comment: @BrianC . The framework needs a sorting key. Without it , it will throw an exception.

Comment: @Mahmoud Ben Hassine . Thank you for watching all spring batch related queries on stackoverflow. Appreciate your time and inputs.

Comment: You are welcome! Glad to see you fixed your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the workaround I found. The sorting key I was using "type" had 3 distinct records. I am not sure whether this would have been a problem. I added an extra identity column to my view and added that(row_num) to sorting key which resolved the issue.

Exp:

```sql
create or alter view my_view as
select *, row_number() over (order by (select 1)) row_num
from (select * from tab1
union
select * from tab2
union
select * from tab3)x;
```

```java
@Bean
public PagingQueryProvider pagingQueryProvider() throws Exception {
    SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean = new SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean();
    Map<String, Order> sortKey = new HashMap<>();
    sortKey.put("row_num", Order.ASCENDING);
    sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setSelectClause("select *");
    sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setFromClause("from dse.zyntrack_web_view");
    sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setSortKeys(sortKey);
    return sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.getObject();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fetch work for field key type.

```
OraclePagingQueryProvider queryProvider = new OraclePagingQueryProvider();
queryProvider.setSelectClause("*");
queryProvider.setFromClause("from MEMENTO_REQUEST");

Map<String, Order> sortKeys = new HashMap<>(1);

sortKeys.put("PROG_REQUEST_ID", Order.ASCENDING);
```

If you sort for a field that isn't PK the fetch is minor that all records in the table

Answer (score 0):

Also in my case, the problem seems to be in the *OraclePagingQueryProvider* and its sorting setup. My original code was like this:

```
OraclePagingQueryProvider queryProvider = new OraclePagingQueryProvider();

queryProvider.setSelectClause("id, status");
queryProvider.setFromClause("cms.cms_card");
queryProvider.setWhereClause("card_type_id = :cardTypeId");
queryProvider.setSortKeys(Map.of("status", Order.ASCENDING));
```

As the solution, I just modified sorting clause in this way:

```
queryProvider.setSortKeys(Map.of("status", Order.ASCENDING, "id", Order.ASCENDING));
```

Adding PK fixed the issue and the order of the results was still as expected.